# Unable to read prophet model from ADLS to python

Tags: python, pandas, azure, facebook-prophet

Trying to read prophet model json file strored on ADLS gen2 container from python using below code

```
from prophet.serialize import model_from_json

def reading_model_file():
    credentials = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
    dataLakeServiceClient = DataLakeServiceClient(
    account_url="https://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(ACCOUNT_NAME),
    credential=credentials
    )
    file_system_client = dataLakeServiceClient.get_file_system_client(FILE_SYSTEM_NAME)
    source_directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client(SOURCE_DIRECTORY)
    source_file_client = source_directory_client.get_file_client(file_name) 
    source_file_contents = source_file_client.download_file().readall()
    return source_file_contents

model = model_from_json(reading_model_file())`
```

getting below error message:

*TypeError: Cannot use .astype to convert from timezone-aware dtype to timezone-naive dtype. Use obj.tz_localize(None) or obj.tz_convert('UTC').tz_localize(None) instead.*

python - 3.10.4
prophet - 1.1.4
pandas - 2.1.0

saving the model json files from databricks with the below code

```
with open('model.json', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(model_to_json(model))
```

also I am able to read the model files successfully on databricks only.

Databricks:
python - 3.9.5
prophet - 1.1.4
pandas - 1.3.4

Comment: the error message is this: `TypeError: Cannot use .astype to convert from timezone-aware dtype to timezone-naive dtype.`

Comment: This error occurs when trying to convert a Pandas DataFrame or Series that contains `timezone-aware` datetime data to a `timezone-naive` dtype using the `.astype()` method... so ytou need to validate the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I got the same error as you.

[image]

This is because usage of different pandas version while saving the model and loading the model.

In databricks, you save the model using **pandas==1.3.4**.
So load the model with the same pandas version.

```
pip install pandas==1.3.4
```

and run your code.

[image]

By default, in databricks pandas version will be **1.4.2** you can use the same in both environments to load and save the model
or you can upgrade it to **2.1.0** in both environments.

My suggestion is, try to save the model in latest version of pandas.

Comment: Yes, I updated pandas version on databricks. it is working fine now. Thanks